# excel vba last row variable not computing

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the lines:

```
Dim lastrowmonth as Integer, PMARow As Integer
lastRowMonth = Cells(1 & "," & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do While PMARow < lastRowMonth + 1
```

However it keeps telling me that `lastRowMonth = 1`and as such wont let me access my code, inside the `do while`. Any advice here as there are 1400 filled cells in column A and ideally I want to move on to changing `1` to a variable to move through other columns.

Any help would be grand!

Comment: If you're using `Cells`, it is `Cells(row, column)` not the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lastRowMonth = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
```

And maybe it would be a good idea to declare `lastRowMonth` as a `Long` to be sure because in excel there are more rows than an `Integer` can take

Comment: No problem @CJones.  And, I don't know you but I'm pretty sure you're not an idiot :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the second line to:

```
lastRowMonth = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```